# How come Sam's clothes always fit after every Leap?

Tags: time-travel, quantum-leap

In the TV series of "Quantum Leap", the official line was that Sam's physical body leaped from life to life, with only an "aura" of the person he'd replaced remaining behind to "fool" the people around him. Small children, people with mental handicaps and fellow Leapers could see through the aura and see him as Sam. (In the novels, it was different - only Sam's soul travelled in time.) Having his body Leap meant that he could do things the person he'd replaced couldn't, such as see when he was supposed to be blind or walk when he'd apparently had both legs amputated.

So why, when he Leaped into someone a lot smaller than himself, was there not a massive ripping of clothes?

Comment: Wait, there were other leapers? :-o

Comment: Why do you think he's leaping into them **physically**?? My understanding was that it's the opposite. He's leaping in mentally, and we, as viewers, see him in his own body because it means they get to keep the same actor every week.

Comment: It was established in the series that he was indeed Leaping physically - I can't remember which episode off hand, but it was relatively early on.

Comment: There were the Evil Leapers, the first of whom was called Alia. They were able to see each other as Sam and Alia after touching, though their mirror images remained as Jimmy and (I think) Jimmy's sister-in-law.

Comment: Wikipedia also states that this is a physical leap - *"When Sam leaps, his body is physically present in the past, although he appears to others as the person he leaped into. In one case, after leaping into a Vietnam veteran that had lost both legs, Sam could still walk normally but appeared to others as if he was floating. "*

Comment: @Catija: The show established it. Personally I wish they hadn't.

Comment: Perhaps his own clothes Leapt with him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series itself was sometimes inconsistent on this fact (as well as other things about how leaping works), and there was no answer given in the show itself to my knowledge, so any answer is likely to be speculative at best.

Although the canonicity is not the best, it is addressed briefly in the Quantum Leap comic, issue #12, "Waiting" (in which Sam leaps into a recluse who operates a gas station in the middle of nowhere, waiting for someone to come along who's life he's affecting, and he and Al just talk).

> Al: Remember what I said?  Paradoxes **don't matter** in the real world.  Here's something else for you to chew on...
>
> Al: Why is it that whenever you leap into somebody's place, their **clothes** always seem to fit you?  You've been petite women and even children, but you can **still** wear their clothes.
>
> Sam: Gee, you know, I **never** thought about that...
>
> Al: It's not something you **would** normally think about.  You just wear the clothes and don't notice that they fit, even if they **are** tight or loose sometimes.  Look at what you're wearing now.  Lucky is a **scrawny** little guy, barely four and a half feet tall, but the clothes are on you and they're **not** torn to shreds!
>
> Sam: So... do you have any **ideas** about this one, Professor Calavicci?
>
> Al: I confess that one had me **stumped**.  But Gooshie came up with a possible answer.
>
> Sam: **Gooshie!?**
>
> Al: Yeah, the **little guy** with the bad breath who--
>
> Sam: I remember **who** Gooshie is, I just don't remember him ever coming up with an **answer** to anything before.
>
> Al: This actually **almost** makes sense.  Gooshie figures that the leap causes a **disturbance** in the molecular structure of the clothes, making them **unstable**, so that they can stretch or shrink to fit you.
>
> Sam: Clothes made of **unstable molecules**?
>
> Al: Maybe.
>
> Sam: Gooshie reads too many **comic books**.
>
> Al: Probably.
>
> Sam: But, **wait** a minute.
>
> Sam: I had to take off the **boots** right after I leaped in here because they were **too tight**.  Why would that have happened?
>
> Al: Uhhh... maybe they were too  tight for "Lucky" **before** you got here, but he was just used to it.  I don't know.
>
> Al: Anyway, it just proves that there is a whole lot about your quantum leaping that we still don't **understand**... things we can't account for...

But that's not really an answer either.  I'm unaware of any official (albeit again, possibly non-canon) attempt to answer in any other media.

Fans always come up with their own theories, of course, and, for me, the best fanwank answer I've read was that Sam's body is somehow "mapped" into the space the original person would occupy, like say, imagine a stretchy balloon with Sam's face on it could be filled with a different amount of air and shoved into a set of clothes of somebody else, but a far more complex three-dimensional balloon of his entire body.

Comment: Are the random bold words actually bold in the comic? Is there a reason for them?

Comment: Yes.  I figured since I don't have a scanner or scanned page on hand I'd try to keep as close to the text as possible, including bolding.

Comment: I like the idea that Sam's body is "mapped" into the appropriate space, as it would also account for the fact that other people aren't talking to his chin or his chest if the person he Leaped into is shorter than him, or wondering why they're suddenly having to look up to look into the eyes of someone they know.

Comment: @Catija The bolding of words like that is a comic book staple. Sometimes it's just words that are important, or just to keep reader attention. But, in this case, it appears to primarily be words that were spoken with a slight bit of emphasis. But only slightly, to the point that normal writing wouldn't bother using italics or bold at all.